# How can I transfer df1 to df2 by using dictionary or other method

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I am using python 3 and have a DataFrame shown as df1 and how can I transfer df1 into df2?

Many thanks !

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy ! Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please, after doing the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), be sure to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, edit the question adding the epected output. Also, please edit the question providing the data in text format (not image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the column names and store them in a temporary dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame(df1.T.apply(lambda x: x.index)[0].str.split("_EXP_").tolist(), columns=['name1', 'name2'])

print(temp)

    name1        name2
0      5R      25Delta
1      5R      50Delta
2      5R     -25Delta
3      3R      25Delta
4      3R      50Delta
5      3R     -25Delta
```

Add values to the temporary table.

```
temp['val'] = df1.T[0].values

print(temp)

    name1        name2     val
0      5R      25Delta       1
1      5R      50Delta       2
2      5R     -25Delta       3
3      3R      25Delta       4
4      3R      50Delta       5
5      3R     -25Delta       6
```

Then use the `pivot` function to create a reshaped table.

```
df2 = temp.pivot(index='name2', columns='name1', values='val')

print(df2)

name1        3R  5R
name2
-25Delta      6   3
25Delta       4   1
50Delta       5   2
```

If your index and column order matters, then reorder them.

```
# Reset index manually
df2 = df2.reindex(["25Delta", "50Delta", "-25Delta"]) 

# Reverse the column order
df2 = df2[df2.columns[::-1]] 

print(df2)

name1        5R  3R
name2
25Delta       1   4
50Delta       2   5
-25Delta      3   6
```